# How to speed up AVD boot (more detailed)?

Tags: android, sdk, cpu, android-virtual-device, ram

I know that question was already asked. But I'm adding some more details and asking more precise questions that can solve this problem.

Actually, when I start an AVD with 312 MB of RA it does manage to do it respectably (even if it's considered slow).
But when I ask for 512 MB of RAM, it's like it will never start at all (in fact never), and noticed that the AVD only works on a single core a 100%. Plus it populates the RAM quite quickly until it reaches around 175MB (5-10MB/s) and then slows down dramatically (250KB/s).

How can this happen and how can I do for preventing such RAM filling performance drops ? Or even set the AVD to use more than one single core ?

I run this on a Core I5, with 4GB of RAM.

Edit: Why so much downvotes ?

Problem solved: Templating from a Nexus 5 messed up everything, went to Nexus 4 and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

a. Use the Intel system images available on the SDK manager. 
b. Use [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture) software by Intel to make your emulator run faster. 
c. Use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: d)Skip the emulator and just test on a device.  Far quicker and more accurate.

Comment: My Genymotion emulator is almost as fast as my Nexus 5 and I don't need to tap around on the device but can use the mouse and keyboard. 
Plus sometimes you need an emulator, for example for sending fake SMS, sending fake GPS signals or running the hierarchy viewer. 
But you're right, testing on a real device is essential.

Comment: You can fake GPS signals with mock location, and no reason to fake SMSes-  send real ones.  Using the mouse and keyboard is actually a disadvantage in many cases-  you use a mouse differently than a touch screen if you're doing motion testing, for example.  You'll get different patterns.  Except for automated checkin testing I think using emulators are a bad idea, you get more accurate results with fewer issues on the device itself.

Comment: I must do my project on the AVD, and cannot use any alternatives, even an intel x86 image.

Comment: I'm a fan of (c). Multiple devices without the cost!